# Rails select over integer field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I post a product I put the quantity of the product, so how I get this quantity with select helper on product page?

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :quantity %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

So I read the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) and the closest that I could get is this:

```
<%= select_tag "Quantity", options_from_collection_for_select(@product, 'id', 'quantity') %>
```

Comment: The question might need some more work

Comment: have you tried `select("product", "quantity", 1..100)`, being 100 the max quantity.

Comment: What exactly you wanted to do here??

Comment: thank's ismaelga and show i get those numbers from db?

Comment: get just the quantity numbers from db with select helper

Comment: what numbers you want to get? And when?

Comment: the quantity numbers! when i select.